# Compact letter display for kruskal- wallis Dunn post-hoc test on R

Tags: r, posthoc, kruskal-wallis, dunn.test

This code is working but it uses Fisher LSD test or I need compact letter display for kruskal-wallis Dunn post hoc test. Does anyone have a solution ?

```
library(agricolae)

kruskal_cld <- kruskal(MR$hauteur, MR$distance, group=TRUE, p.adj="bonferroni")$groups
kruskal_cld
cld <- as.data.frame(kruskal_cld) 

cld$ordre <- c(6,3,1,2,4,5)
cld <- cld[order(cld$ordre), ]

ggplot(data=MR, aes(x=distance, y=hauteur,col=distance))+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2")+
  scale_alpha(0.5)+
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 1), size = 0.5)+
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sd, size=0.4, col="black")+
 geom_text(data = cld, aes(label = cld$groups, y = 50, x = ordre), vjust = -0.5, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

I tried this code (find it on stackoverflow) but then I realise agricolae package do not use Dunn test but Fisher LSD to display the letters. I need to do it with the Dunn test for my analyze.

Comment: I don't know that I agree with the *agricolae* package approach of using LSD as post-hoc test for Kruskal-Wallis. Dunn test (1964) is probably the most common post-hoc.  There are others devised for Kruskal-Wallis, including Conover test and Nemenyi test.  In general, just be careful you're conducting the correct test, since these names may be given to other, different, tests.

Answer (score 1):

If it is fine for you to switch to another package capable of performing the dunnTest function, then the `FSA` package is one solution. Then, using the `rcompanion` package you can get the compact letter display of your comparisons. As I do not have access to your `MR` data, I used the `mtcars` data from `R` to show how to do it in this way:

```
# install and load the required packages
library(FSA)
library(rcompanion)

# using mtcars as example data and a new assignment as df
df <- mtcars
# using cyl as factor variable and hp as dependent variable
df$cyl <- factor(df$cyl,levels = c("4","6","8"))
```

**# running kruskal-wallis test if there is any difference between groups**

```
kruskal.test(hp ~ cyl,
             data = df)

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  hp by cyl
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 25.222, df = 2, p-value = 3.336e-06
```

**# running post hoc Dunn test**

```
Phocdunn <- dunnTest(hp ~ cyl,
              data=df,
              method="bonferroni")    # Can adjust p-values;

Phocdunn
 
  Comparison         Z      P.unadj        P.adj
1      4 - 6 -1.823778 6.818569e-02 2.045571e-01
2      4 - 8 -4.989580 6.051057e-07 1.815317e-06
3      6 - 8 -2.437999 1.476883e-02 4.430648e-02

# extract the post hoc from Phocdunn
Phocdunns <- Phocdunn$res
```

**# Compact letter display of comparisons**

```
cld <- cldList(comparison = Phocdunns$Comparison,
        p.value    = Phocdunns$P.adj,
        threshold  = 0.05)[1:2]

names(cld)[1]<-"cyl" # change the name of grouping factor according to the dataset (df)
cld
# here it shows the cyl levels 4 and 6 are not different as they have same letter #but different from cyl 8
    cyl    Letter
1     4      a
2     6      a
3     8      b
```

**# visualization of comparisons using ggplot (you need to adjust the plot arguments based on your dataset)**

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=cyl, y=hp,col=cyl))+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2")+
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 1), size = 0.5)+
  theme_bw() +
  geom_text(data = cld, aes(label = cld$Letter, y = 300, x = cyl), 
            vjust = -0.5,
            hjust= 0.5,
            fontface = "bold",
            size=3.5,
            check_overlap = F)+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]